# Nginx Load balancer support HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: nginx

I have configured a Nginx load balancer so it can split traffic with more Nginx+PHP5-FPM servers. The load balancer Nginx website.com.conf (vhost) is configured as this:

```
upstream backend  {
    ip_hash;
    server IP_NGINX_PHP5FPM_NODE1;
    server IP_NGINX_PHP5FPM_NODE2;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.website.com website.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
    }
}
```

So when an user visits the site via HTTP the load balancer can use two nodes to handle the traffic. All works fine with HTTP but I need it to support also HTTPS. So I edited it as this:

```
upstream backend  {
    ip_hash;
    server IP_NGINX_PHP5FPM_NODE1;
    server IP_NGINX_PHP5FPM_NODE2;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  www.website.com website.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/www/website.com/ssl/website-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/website.com/ssl/diosesbueno.key;
    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /var/www/website.com/ssl/trustchain.crt;
    ssl_dhparam /var/www/website.com/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
    }
}
```

It works if I visit the site via HTTPS but Firefox says the website contains unencrypted elements and gives an alert, see this screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/m15g9zgzh/

Can someone help me fix this issue ?

Comment: You don't need `ssl on` directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely has nothing to do with your nginx config.

Chances are you're referencing some files in the page - images, JavaScript, CSS, etc. - via HTTP links. Make sure you're using relative URLs. Chrome's web inspector's error console will actually tell you the exact URLs that are triggering the warning.

Comment: Thank you, these info have helped me. I have added an answer below with more details about how I solved the mixed content issue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ceejayoz and @Martin answers I found the issue related to the mixed content HTTPS/HTTP in the website pages. Basically, the backends Nginx nodes were sending via HTTP the website content to the Nginx load blancer HTTPS. And due to this, the web page showed to the user had some HTTP links inside the code. So to fix this, I have added support for SSL also in the Nginx nodes, and I modified the Nginx load balancer vhost to support https in the proxy pass directive:

```
proxy_pass  https://backendssl;
```

Inside the SSL server:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
```

And this is the content of the upstream backendssl:

```
upstream backendssl  {
    ip_hash;
    server IP_ADDRESS_NODE1:443;
    server IP_ADDRESS_NODE2:443;
}
```

Since the website needed HTTPS connections always, I also added:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.website.com website.com;
    return       301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

In the Nginx load balancer vhost.

Hope this can be of help for other users!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that error is related to your server setup, but due to something on the page being included using http. Take a look at the network tab in FireBug and see if anything is fetched via. http. Usually its a .js or css